# update value in json array file

Tags: java, gson

I'm reading a json file that contains a json array and I'm trying to update some key values in all of the objects in the jason array and write the new updated json array to a different file.

The file with the following json array inside it:

```
 [
      {
        "info": "old text"
        "sometext": "old text",
        "Id": 2,
        "No": 12,
      },
      {
        "info": "old text"
        "sometext": "old text",
        "Id": 68,
        "No": 22,
      },
      {
        "info": "old text"
        "sometext": "old text",
        "Id": 87,
        "No": 15,
      }

 ]
```

I want to update the values of the info & sometext keys in all the objects in the json array such that the output to the new file with the updated json array  is (this is my desired output that I want to achieve through my code) :

```
 [
      {
        "info": "new text"
        "sometext": "new text",
        "Id": 2,
        "No": 12,
      },
      {
        "info": "new text"
        "sometext": "new text",
        "Id": 68,
        "No": 22,
      },
      {
        "info": "new text"
        "sometext": "new text",
        "Id": 87,
        "No": 15,
      }

 ]
```

this is my code so far :

```
final String JSON_PATH = "old.json";
final String JSON_PATH1 = "new.json";

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(JSON_PATH1));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JSON_PATH));
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray arrayObj = parser.parse(br).getAsJsonArray();


for(int i=0; i < arrayObj.size();i++) {
    JsonObject burObj = arrayObj.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    String  old_info = burObj.get("info").getAsString();
    String  old_sometext = burObj.get("sometext").getAsString();
    burObj.addProperty(NewTextGen(old_info), "info");
    burObj.addProperty(NewTextGen(old_sometext), "sometext");
    burObj.remove(old_info);
    burObj.remove(old_sometext);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
    gson.toJson(arrayObj, new JsonWriter(bw));
}
```

> when I run this code I get gibberish output of both new and old values
>   and not my desired output.

gibberish output:

```
 [
      {
        "info": "old text"
        "sometext": "old text",
        "info": "new text"
        "sometext": "new text",
        "Id": 2,
        "No": 12,
      },
      {
        "info": "old text"
        "sometext": "old text",
        "info": "new text"
        "sometext": "new text",
        "Id": 68,
        "No": 22,
      },
      {
        "info": "old text"
        "sometext": "old text",
        "info": "new text"
        "sometext": "new text",
        "Id": 87,
        "No": 15,
      },
      {
        "info": "old text"
        "sometext": "old text",
        "info": "new text"
        "sometext": "new text",
      }

 ]
```

**please note that** *old text & new text are just dummy text and not the actual text, same with NewTextGen() dummy method  as I'm only seeking to know what I'm doing wrong in my code*

---

**UPDATE**
Solved my problem, check answers

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: no errors , I don't get my desired output when I run my code

Comment: - Do you close the BufferedWriter?

- Try removing old properties first and then add new properties.

Comment: surely the parameters to the `addProperty(propertyName,value)` method are the wrong way around? And what are you trying to achieve with the `remove(propertyName)` calls when you pass in the property value?

Comment: tried what you said but same gibberish output with old and new values together (not my desired output)

Comment: @ Simon G I'm gonna double check

Comment: @ Simon G what I'm trying to achieve is , remove the old text value such that the new text can replace it

Comment: @ Simon G checked and the addProperty(propertyName,value) method are the Not the wrong way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved my problem**

After some grueling trial and error it turned out that I needed to create my BufferedWriter inside the loop where I iterate over the elements of the objects in the json array. Also I needed to flush() the BufferedWriter at the end. There was no need for the .remove() at all.

```
final String JSON_PATH = "old.json";
final String JSON_PATH1 = "new.json";

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(JSON_PATH1));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JSON_PATH));
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray arrayObj = parser.parse(br).getAsJsonArray();


for (int i = 0; i < arrayObj.size(); i++) {

     JsonObject burObj = arrayObj.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

     burObj.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("info", NewTextGen(burObj.get("info").getAsString());
     burObj.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("sometext", NewTextGen(burObj.get("sometext").getAsString());

     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
     FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(JSON_PATH1);
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fr);
     gson.toJson(arrayObj, new JsonWriter(bw));
     bw.flush();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the whole 'arrayObj' on every iteration. Probably intention was to write out 'burObj'.

```
gson.toJson(burObj, new JsonWriter(bw));
```

Comment: does not solve my problem, I'm still getting the old text concatenated with the new text and not my desired output (see my question for the the desired output that I want)

Comment: Did you perhaps copy-paste my code over to test it?
I actually had a typo there, my answer was just the same as your original code. Fixed the typo.

Comment: Could you post the exact text output you're getting? That should be very helpful.

Comment: I was aware of the burObj typo and I fixed it when I applied to to my code 
I'll update my post with the gibberish output

Comment: No clue why might there be 4 entries in the output as opposed to 3 input entries. But I agree with what Simon G said before about remove():
Should most likely use the name of property instead of the value, so burObj.remove("info");

Comment: tried what Simon G said but I end up with a blank file thus not solving my problem, np thank you for thinking along and trying to help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
JSONObject json =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
json.put("info", "new text");
```

Here the JSONObject will have each json and json.put(key,value) will put the value based on the key

Comment: I'm using the gson library, there is no put method

Comment: Try this for the GSON    

    JsonArray jsonArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonArray();
        JsonObject firstObject = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        firstObject.addProperty("info", "new text");

Comment: I get the gibberish output as in the old values still exist